# Batch-file wrong input fix?

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off
:start
cls
color e
echo YOU HAVE WON $1,000,000! WHAT WILL YOU DO? 
echo.
echo =================
echo -Take it (1)
echo -Leave it (2)
echo -Double it (3)
echo =================
echo.
set /p INPUT=Please specify your answer: 
If /i "%INPUT%" == "1" goto 1
If /i "%INPUT%" == "2" goto 2
If /i "%INPUT%" == "3" goto 3
If /i "%INPUT%" == "Jonah" goto Jonah
If /i "%INPUT%" == "" goto Wrong
```

I have a strange problem. Above is a code and for some reason, when I type in "INPUT" something like 'Aiden' it would think it meant '1'. Is there a way to make every wrong answer goto wrong. (Wrong answers like Aiden which isn't even specified there. But not only Aiden, any other thing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your if statements you need to put a catch-all GOTO statement so if none of the others work, it will go to wrong instead of just continuing into the block right below

```
@echo off
:start
cls
color e
echo YOU HAVE WON $1,000,000! WHAT WILL YOU DO? 
echo.
echo =================
echo -Take it (1)
echo -Leave it (2)
echo -Double it (3)
echo =================
echo.
set /p INPUT=Please specify your answer: 
If /i "%INPUT%" == "1" goto 1
If /i "%INPUT%" == "2" goto 2
If /i "%INPUT%" == "3" goto 3
If /i "%INPUT%" == "Jonah" goto Jonah
goto Wrong
```